# How to free memory when moving between SpriteKit scenes

Tags: ios7, ios8, sprite-kit

I made a spritekit game with 10 different scenes with a single base scene which directs to each of the scenes. when I move to and from every scene, memory keeps going up, assuming due to texture caching, as explained here before.

The problem is that memory keeps going up to 300 MB and in weak devices it crashes after 3-4 scenes. I have tried to "free" memory using a cleanup function:

```c
- (void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {

    [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        SKNode* child = obj;
        [child removeAllActions];
    }];

    [self removeAllChildren];       
}
```

However, this doesn't help. Any ideas how to solve this?

This is my main (and only) ViewController:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
//    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    MainMenu *scene = [MainMenu sceneWithSize: self.view.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

and my switch to scene code:

```c
- (void)switchToRoom
{
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:0.5];

    SKScene * scene = [[RoomScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];

    [self.view presentScene:scene transition:transition];

}
```

**UPDATE:**

After 3 days of struggling I found out that my bad practice was using a "curtain" styled animation to navigate between scenes. The problem with this method is that a "curtain" is at the size of the screen, and an Atlas of curtains with ~30 textures is HUGE, and probably what caused the memory to run so high, I am not sure why it caused a leak alike behavior, but when reducing the number of frames inside the atlas to around 10, I no longer see memory goes that high, and it looks like that there is no leak.

Another bad practice for this situation was to use "preloadTextures:textures" method, which appears to consume a lot of memory for this type of animation. When I removed it, performance became even better.

Comment: Have you tried just calling that code before you call `presentScene:` instead of putting it in `willMoveFromView:`?

Comment: Also, did you add a log or breakpoint to make sure `willMoveFromView:` is getting called?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work ..

Comment: show us the code you use to create the scene

Comment: Can you update your question with more (relevant) code...For example the part where you make a transition to the other scenes ?

Comment: Why is the Room scene initialized as an SKScene and not a room scene

Comment: Doesn't need any methods from `RoomScene`. Should be fine. It is still an `SKScene`. A `RoomScene` object is still what's initialized.

Comment: Did you try setting old scene to nil before presenting the new scene?

Comment: Obviously something isn't getting deallocated. The easiest thing to do is load your app up in the allocations instrument, check the object count of objects being used in that scene, and see what's not being deallocated. Then you can go another level deeper and find the + and - retains and see where you have an extra retain or should have another -.

Comment: I ran instruments and nothing is being leaked. Just not being deallocated

Comment: The issue only happens in iPhone4 & 4S .. any ideas?

Comment: In my experience with Sprite Kit what you refer to as a leak instruments will not catch. What you need to do is look at #persistent and persistent bytes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ruc7d1qsjv890g/screen_shot_2015-07-28_at_10.46.25_am.png?dl=0 Normally that will give you a clue as to what is still being retained that you didn't expect.

Comment: I am guessing it is an issue on all devices it just happens much faster on the 4 and 4s.

Comment: The thing is that memory deallocation happens in 5s & 6, but I don't see it in 4&4S

Comment: The only other guess I would have is that you are calling something in your update loop too quickly and newer devices can keep up but older ones can't. I can't remember for sure but 4 and 4s also might run at 30 fps by default, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Check to make sure you are calling switchToRoom once per scene. If you are spamming it in the update and it has a .5 second delay on it that could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SK is suppose to take care of all that by itself baring you have a retain loop. However I too have run into this issue. My solution ended up being to manually set everything to nil:

```c
-(void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {

    // for all arrays
    [self.myArray removeAllObjects]; // and so on...

    // for all objects
    self.worldNode = nil;
    self.player = nil; // and so on...
}
```

As you already stated, there will be some increase due to caching but you should level at some point. If this does not work, try running Instruments to see if you can spot a leak.

Comment: setting 'nil' for nodes won't release the preloaded textures from cache.

Comment: sangony is right if you are looking to release textures from memory remove texture atlas which generates those textures  removeing textures does not help you remove and add texturesatlas depends on your requirement this would solve your problem

Comment: @Yuvals - Setting objects to nil does not automatically release anything but it does for SK to release when SK deems fit to do so. You said you ran instruments and there is no leak. You also said your app crashes after 3 to 4 scene changes. Taking what you stated at face value, either you are retaining objects through scene transitions or your code has a logical error and is creating too many objects which eat up your memory.

Comment: @sangony I think this is not the case - looks like the issue is a result of using large amount of texture atlas. However, I would expect spritekit to free them and not cache until memory overkill